# add a specific css class to the two first elment then skeep the next two element and so one using ngFor in Angular and flex

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, ngfor

I have this code, to display list of products, using *ngFor in Angular:

```
<div class="container-products">
  <div class="item-product" *ngFor="let product of ['product A', 'product B', 'product C', 'product D']; let index = index">
    <div [ngClass]="{'color-gray': index % 2 === 0}">{{ product }}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

with this CSS:

```
  .container-products{ 
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
     }
     .item-product{
        flex: 50%;
     }
     .color-gray {
        background-color: gray;
     }
```

And I have the result like this:
[my table with color gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ4Ls.png)
My question is what can I put instead index % 2 === 0 in the html to have the two first one in gray skeep the two next one and so one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected style with only CSS and [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
div.item-product:nth-child(4n-3),
div.item-product:nth-child(4n-2) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

With this you're making groups of 4 elements, and then taking:

- The 4th element minus 3 (so the 1st of the group of 4)
- The 4th element minus 2 (so the 2nd of the group of 4)

Example with your own code (with angular removed for clarity):

```css
.container-products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-product {
  flex: 50%;
}

div.item-product:nth-child(4n-3),
div.item-product:nth-child(4n-2) {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-products">
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product G</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-product">
    <div>Product H</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution 